# The geometry of the group of automorphisms of a manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, manifolds, automorphism-groups

Given a manifold $M$, the group $Aut(M)$ is made of diffeomorphisms $M\to M$. Since the complete vector fields on $M$ form an infinite dimensional Lie algebra, and each generates a 1 dimensional Lie group. It would seem that the automorphisms generated by composing these group actions would be the connected component of $Aut(M)$ with the identity. It looks like $Aut(M)$ is a manifold and it's tangent space is the complete vector fields of $M$.

I have some question. Does the infinite dimensional Lie algebra of complete vector fields have a natural topology? Does $Aut(M)$ have a natural topology? Does it have a differentiable structure? What type of things can be said about $Aut(M)$? What would be good resources to learn more about this topic?

Comment: If you search for $\operatorname{Diff}(M)$ rather than $\operatorname{Aut}(M)$ you should find plenty of references. Hirsch's book on Differential Topology might be a good starting point.

Comment: Augustin Banyaga is an expert on this topic.

Comment: $Diff(M)$ has a few natural topologies, and they tend to all agree (within a differentiability class) when $M$ is compact.  Some classical work in the 70's says these are Frechet manifolds and they are principally governed by their homotopy types.   One place to start would be here: https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/Papers/Diff%28M%292012.pdf